# Autoclicker or Simulate a click< Code Included >

Tags: click, mouse

I think this might be helpful and easy to modify the code for an auto clicker or to simulate a mouse click in any C# Application Here is my code. I am using 2 buttons for the timer one for ON and one for OFF, and then a text box and a button to see if it works by just adding a 1 in the text box each time the button is pressed. The code clicks the mouse where your cursors current position is. Hope this Helps. Feel free to make any code suggestions.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace AutoClicker
{
    public partial class Form1: Form
    {

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, uint dwExtraInfo);
        //Mouse actions
        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

    }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                  uint X = (uint)Cursor.Position.X;
                  uint Y = (uint)Cursor.Position.Y;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;

        }
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            uint X = (uint)Cursor.Position.X;
            uint Y = (uint)Cursor.Position.Y;
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
        }
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1. Text + "1";
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this code helps